# Unable to save the data from checkboxes and radiobuttons using modelForm

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

model.py

```
    class FormData(models.Model):
        email = models.EmailField()
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        text_area = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        radio_buttons = models.CharField(max_length=25)
        check_boxes = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.email
```

forms.py

```
    class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = FormData
            fields = ['text_area','email','full_name']
            widgets = {
                'text_area': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 10}),
            }
        TYPE_CHOICES = [('s', 'small'),('m', 'medium'),('b', 'big')]
        check_boxes = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

        CHOICES = [(1, 'One'),(2, 'Two'),(3, 'Three'),(4, 'Four')]
        radio_buttons = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

views.py

```
    def home(request):
        title = 'Welcome'
        form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
        context = {"title":title,"form":form}

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False) 
            instance.save()
            context = {"title":"Thank You!"}

        return render(request,"home.html",context)
```

home.html

```
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

The problem is that I can't seem to understand how to save the data from the `checkboxes` and the `radiobuttons`. The form gets submitted successfully but when I look in the database the field of `check_boxes` is empty and the `radio_buttons` field shows a value "`False`" while I need my manual values as defined in the `CHOICES` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added two extra fields in your form which you have not mentioned in `fields`. Change your form like this.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FormData
        fields = ['text_area','email','full_name', 'check_boxes', 'radio_buttons']
        widgets = {
            'text_area': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 10}),
        }
    TYPE_CHOICES = [('s', 'small'),('m', 'medium'),('b', 'big')]
    check_boxes = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    CHOICES = [(1, 'One'),(2, 'Two'),(3, 'Three'),(4, 'Four')]
    radio_buttons = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Comment: that was a silly mistake...thanks. But that doesn't solve the problem of `radio_buttons`. It still saves only `True` or `False` whereas i need the values 1 or 2 or 3 as defined in the `CHOICES` list.

Comment: you should check by placing breakpoints that if you are getting value right or wrong when saving your form.